# How is this program coming along?

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting

Instructions:

> Write a program that will read a line of text that ends
>   with a period, which serves as a sentinel value. Display all the
>   letters that occur in the text, one per line and in alphabetical
>   order, along with the number of times each letter occurs in the text.
>   Use an array of base type int of length 26 so that the element at
>   index 0 contains the number of `a`s. and index 1 contain number of `b`s etc.

```
package alphabetize;

 import java.util.*;

 public class Alphabetize 
 {

private static void number(String s) 
{
    int[] array = new int[26];
    s = s.toUpperCase();
    System.out.println(s);

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) 
    {
        if (s.charAt(i) >= 'A' && s.charAt(i) <= 'Z') 
        {
            ++array[s.charAt(i) - 'A'];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i) 
    {
        System.out.println("|" + (char) ('A' + i) + "|" + array[i] + "|");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String aString = ".";
    while (true) 
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter sentence with a period to end");
        aString = keyboard.nextLine();
        if (".".equals(aString)) 
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        number(aString);
    }
}
}
```

Still having problem with the period thing.. it does not seem to work the way i did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering this is a homework and instructions are very specific, you should read the text character by character instead of using built-in functions

If your text file was something like

```
abcabca.
```

The output should be something a appears three times, b appears two times etc etc.

So your algo should be something like

1. Read next character
2. If char is period goto 5
3. If char is space goto 1.
4. If char is between a <-> z. update the counter in arr[0..25] and goto 1
5. output arr[0..25] one per line

Comment: shouldn't arr be [0..25] instead of [0..26]?

Answer (score 1):

Was it mandated that this assignment is done in Java?  The whole idea of a "sentinal character" rather than just using a line terminator is pretty bizarre.

Anyway, you can achieve the behaviour you want by setting the delimiter of `Scanner`:

```
keyboard.useDelimiter("\\.");
```

As for the looping, a big hint is this:

```
int[] counts;
counts[chars[0] - 'a'] = counts[chars[0] - 'a'] + 1;
```

or simply

```
counts[chars[0] - 'a']++;
```

I'll leave it up to you to include that in a loop.

### Edit

If you *are* looking for character-at-a-time input, I would suggest you use an `InputStreamReader` instead of `Scanner` for your input.  Here's a basic skeleton of what that looks like:

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
while (true) {
    int nextInput = reader.read();

    if (nextInput == -1) {
       System.out.println("End of input reached without sentinal character");
       break;
    } 
    char nextChar = (char) nextInput;
    //deal with next character

}
```

Still, `read()` will typically block until either the end of input is reached (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> from most consoles) or a new line is sent.  Thus the sentinal character is of limited use since you still have to do something after typing ".".

Comment: Hmm, odd.  Character-by-character input from the console is just not very well supported in Java.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to check whether period is there at the end or not. So the last character should be '.'.
2. Then take the length of string before last '.'.
3. For the counting part create an array like u are doing : 
   int [] name = new int[26] 
   where each index starting from 0, 25 corresponds to 'a' till 'z'.

Now you put the string characters in a loop and have to check what that character is like :

```
if its a 'a' : increase the value at index 0 by 1. 
if its a 'd' : increase the value at index 3 by 1.
```

like wise.

later you display the whole array with a, z along with indexes from 0 till 25.

Suggestion: If its not required to use an array, and you can use any other data-structure you can implement the same in a **HashMap** very easily.  by keeping 'a', 'z' as the keys and count as the corresponding values. and then retrieving and showing the values will also be easier.

Answer (score 0):

You need an int array (e.g., `int[] counts = new int[26];`) After you read the input line, examine it character by character in a loop. If the character is a not period, then increment the appropriate element of the counts array. (If the character is `a`, then increment `counts[0]`; if it is `b`, increment `counts[1]`; etc. Hint: you can subtract `a` from the character to get the appropriate index.) When you find a period, exit the loop and print the results (probably using a second loop).